# the scope and priority of variable in c++

Tags: c++, scope, declaration

Could anybody explains to me why the result is 2, which x is using and why.

```
auto x = 0;

int f(int i){
    auto x = 1;
    {
        static auto x = 0;
        x += i;
    }
    return x;
}
int main() {
    cout << f(1) + f(2) <<endl;// result 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to decide if this is C or C++, because they are very different in the case of `auto`. `cout` won't work in C, so I'll remove the C tag.

Comment: i will pay attention the next time thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact this function

```
int f(int i){
    auto x = 1;
    {
        static auto x = 0;
        x += i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

can be rewritten like

```
int f(int i){
    auto x = 1;
    return x;
}
```

because the static variable `x` declared in this block scope

```
{
    static auto x = 0;
    x += i;
}
```

is not used outside the block and does not influence on the returned value of the function. The only side effect of this code block is potential overflowing of the static signed integer variable `x` that has undefined behavior.

So the both function calls `f(1)` and  `f(2)` returns `1` and as a result the expression `f(1) + f(2)` yields `2`.

In the program there are declared three variables `x`. The first one in the global name space

```
auto x = 0;
```

The second one in the outer-most block of the function `f` that hides the declaration of the variable `x` in the global name space.

```
auto x = 1;
```

And the third one is declared in an inner block of the function f

```
{
    static auto x = 0;
    x += i;
}
```

that is not visible outside this inner block.

Answer (score 9):

The inner `x` shadows the outer one, but the mutations only apply to the inner most scope

```
int f(int i){
    auto x = 1;              // consider this "x1"
    {
        static auto x = 0;   // this is "x2"
        x += i;              // mutates "x2" but not "x1"
    }
    return x;                // return "x1" which is still 1
}
```

Therefore

```
f(1) + f(2)                  // 1 + 1 == 2
```

Comment: there is another `auto x=1;` declared outside the function

Comment: @idclev463035818 but that one it not relevant, it's never used

Comment: @Jabberwocky I know that, but OP didnt

Comment: `s/but/so/` ... ?

Answer (score 7):

This is all about variable *shadowing*.

The innermost `x` in function `f` is shadowing the automatic `x` in that function. So that function is equivalent to

```
int f(int){
    auto x = 1;
    return x;
}
```

Note furthermore that the `x` in my abridged version *shadows* the one at global scope.

The function `f` is further abbreviated to

```
int f(int){
    return 1;
}
```

and now the program output should be obvious.